# render form partials in rails activeadmin without using formtastic forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

My clubs.rb file is given below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Club do
    permit_params :name, :email, :admin_id, club_profile_attributes: [:id, :club_id, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :country_id, :lat, :long, :website, :email, :fiscal_number, :phone_number_1, :phone_number_2]
    before_save do |club|
        if user_id = User.find_by_email(params[:club][:email]).try(:id)
            club.admin_id = user_id
        else
            user = User.set_email params[:club][:email]
            club.admin_id = user.id
        end
        club.id = club.club_profile.club_id
    end

    form do |f|
        f.inputs "Details" do
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        #club name
        f.input :name, label: 'Club Name'
        #search for user email field
        f.input :email, label: 'Club Admin Email', input_html: {value: 
        f.object.admin.present? ? f.object.admin.email : ''}
        #club profile and country for form
        f.inputs for: [:club_profile, f.object.club_profile ||   ClubProfile.new] do |ff|
            ff.input :address_1
            ff.input :address_2
            ff.input :city
            ff.input :state
            ff.input :country_id, as: :select, collection: Country.all.collect {|country| [ country.name, country.id]}, include_blank: false
            ff.input :lat
            ff.input :long
            ff.input :website
            #Club email
            ff.input :email, label: 'Club Email'
            ff.input :fiscal_number
            ff.input :phone_number_1
            ff.input :phone_number_2
        end
        f.actions
        end
    end

show do
    attributes_table do
        row "Club Admin Email" do
            club.admin.email
        end
        attributes_table_for club.club_profile do
            row :address_1
            row :address_2
            row :city
            row :state
            row "Country" do
                club.club_profile.country.name
            end
            row :lat
            row :long
            row :website
            row "Club Email" do
                club.club_profile.email
            end
            row :fiscal_number
            row :phone_number_1
            row :phone_number_2
        end
    end
end
end
```

Please help me how to use the partial so that i can use the same partial in the dashboard of activeadmin.
Here in the above code I have written the form for creating new clubs in the active admin and the show code is for displaying the details of the clubs.

Comment: I am a little unclear what you are asking for here. You would like to move this form to a partial, but you would not like to use formtastic? Or does that matter. Would any solution that allows you to share this form with the dashboard work?

Comment: yes I want to make a form partial in active admin that I can use in both the index action of the resource and in the dashboard. What do you recommend is the optimal solution? @AmielMartin

Comment: I think you should be able to use `active_admin_form_for` in a partial. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a partial with the `.html.arb` extension and the `active_admin_form_for` helper.

You can put your form in a partial. You can even make your partial `.arb` instead of `.erb`. The `.arb` extension allows you to write with the ActiveAdmin DSL in the partial.

```
# app/views/clubs/_form.html.arb
active_admin_form_for resource do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    #club name
    f.input :name, label: 'Club Name'
  end

  # etc

  f.actions
end
```

Then, in your dashboard, or wherever else you want to render the form you can use

```
# app/admin/dashboard.rb
render partial: 'clubs/form', locals: { resource: Club.new }

# app/admin/clubs.rb
form partial: 'form'
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution but it is giving undefined method '<' error, I have tried to solve it but it's not working @Amiel Martin

Comment: Hmmm. It's hard to troubleshoot an undefined method error without a backtrace. Can you trace where that undefined method error is coming from?

Comment: I found solution by tracing as you suggested and my error was related to helper which i was eventually be able to solve.